# Housemarks (superimposed & combined letters, heraldry)

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

I am trying to typeset three housemarks from a manuscript (see also images):

- V + R superimposed
- A + B combined
- A and H + S combined

[image: housemarks]
[image: housemark]

However, it's turning out to be harder than I thought. I have the below V+R so far, but the horizontal alignment is off (though I have `halign=center`?!), and it just plain looks bad.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=1cm,
        height=1cm,
        bean arc,
        sharp corners=north,
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
    ]
    \stackinset{c}{-1pt}{c}{-5pt}%
        {\upshape\larger[2] V}%
        {\upshape R}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use picture mode and `\put` each letter by coordinate (or use tikz to do the same)

Comment: What is "picture mode"? googling doesn't seem helpful (I'm very new at tikz et al, having done almost exclusively text so far)

Comment: `\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){A} \put(5,5){V}\end{picture}` (standard latex, no package required, adjust the coordinates to whatever you need (but since you are using tikz for the rest you could position the letters with tikz instead)

Comment: There are [many commercial fonts for producing monograms](https://www.myfonts.com/search/monogram), but all have decorative features not found in your manuscript. Tracing high-resolution photographs in a program like Inkscape may be the best choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this

[image]

But the results are at best "variable" it would be better really to forget that they are letters and just draw the paths directly using tikz, otherwise you are always going to get weird artefacts from rotated serifs etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(5,5){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{1.5}[1]{V}}}
\put(5,5){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{.9}[1]{\itshape R}}}
\end{picture}}
\quad
\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(3,5){\makebox(0,0){A}}
\put(6.5,5.5){\makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{20}{B}}}
\end{picture}}
\quad
\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(2.5,5){\makebox(0,0){I}}
\put(2.5,5){\thicklines\line(1,0){4}}
\put(7,5){\makebox(0,0){S}}
\end{picture}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for now :) I might end up exporting the glyphs from EBGaramond & combining them in Illustrator.

Answer (score 8):

This is mostl a comment on David Carlisle's answer, but it is a bit bit long...

If you want to use existing letters for your `AB`, I would recommend slanting the `A` instead of rotating the `B`. This avoids getting rotated serifs and the B looks more natural:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode
\setbox0\hbox{A}%
\pdfsave
\pdfsetmatrix{1 0 0.35 1}%
\box0\expandafter\kern\the\dimexpr-\wd0\relax\relax
\pdfrestore
\kern.43em
B
\end{document}
```

[image]